# Select the first instance of an action after the previous action

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

So, the subject is super confusing, because I just don't know how to explain with words what I want. I am trying to pull data from a single table with an action. Below is a small sample of what my data would look like.

I need the first instance of each OptIn and OptOut after the previous action for each name.  I have posted my desired results below also.

I'm trying to do this in SQL 2014. I am pulling a blank on this. I thought maybe I could something with a lag and over but I don't fully understand how to use them, so I am confusing myself.

Sample Data:

```
Inst,Acct,First,MI,Last,Activty,ActivtyDate

001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-05-25 12:02:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-05-25 12:37:00.000
001,00000000001111111,KIM,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-06-17 08:43:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-20 11:57:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-20 23:10:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-21 08:46:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-06-27 10:34:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-27 10:35:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-27 23:04:00.000
001,00000000001111111,KIM,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-07-02 11:35:42.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-07-05 15:04:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-07-06 07:57:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-07-06 08:16:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-07-09 08:17:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-03 20:51:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-03 20:51:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-03-08 19:10:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-03-16 06:34:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-18 16:21:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-03-21 16:38:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-22 05:26:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-04-01 15:39:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-04-02 04:06:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-04-06 11:53:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-04-09 12:51:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-04-20 15:21:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-04-20 15:21:00.000
```

Desired Result:

```
Inst,Acct,First,MI,Last,Activty,ActivtyDate

001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-05-25 12:02:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-20 11:57:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-06-27 10:34:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-06-27 10:35:00.000
001,00000000001111111,KIM,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-07-02 11:35:42.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptOut,2019-07-05 15:04:00.000
001,00000000001111111,EDWARD,,BICKLE,OptIn,2019-07-06 07:57:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-03 20:51:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-03-08 19:10:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-18 16:21:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-03-21 16:38:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-03-22 05:26:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-04-01 15:39:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-04-02 04:06:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-04-06 11:53:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptOut,2019-04-09 12:51:00.000
000,00000000002222222,DAWN,M,ADAMS,OptIn,2019-04-20 15:21:00.000
```

Comment: Sample data is nice but it is much nicer if somebody can just copy and paste it. This sample data requires a lot of fiddling to turn into a viable insert. And quite frankly I can't make heads or tails of what you are trying to do here at all.

Comment: "I need the first instance of each OptIn and OptOut after the previous action for each name." So `Inst` and `Acct` have no effect, they are just along for the ride?

Comment: Sorry for not getting the data formatted to your preference. The sample data is for 2 accounts over a year with a number of times they have opted in or opted out of a service. I have been asked to provide a report for a list of accounts (with names) that have performed this action 12 times in a given year. My actual data is thousands of accounts and some of them have performed this action 20 plus times while others only once. They want a report of each time they flipped the action action. However, poorly written software records the action if you duplicate it. So I need to filter those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to identify records whose `activity` is different than the "previous" record:

```
select t.*
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(activity) over(partition by inst, acct order by activityDate) lag_activity
    from mytable t
) t
where lag_activity is null or activity <> lag_activity
order by inst, acct, activityDate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9edeb7b7301cb688e774564a18bf0a8)**:

```
Inst |    Acct | First  | MI   | Last   | Activty | ActivityDate            | lag_activity
---: | ------: | :----- | :--- | :----- | :------ | :---------------------- | :-----------
   1 | 1111111 | EDWARD | null | BICKLE | OptIn   | 2019-05-25 12:02:00.000 | null
   1 | 1111111 | EDWARD | null | BICKLE | OptOut  | 2019-06-20 11:57:00.000 | OptIn
   1 | 1111111 | EDWARD | null | BICKLE | OptIn   | 2019-06-27 10:34:00.000 | OptOut
   1 | 1111111 | EDWARD | null | BICKLE | OptOut  | 2019-06-27 10:35:00.000 | OptIn
   1 | 1111111 | KIM    | null | BICKLE | OptIn   | 2019-07-02 11:35:42.000 | OptOut
   1 | 1111111 | EDWARD | null | BICKLE | OptOut  | 2019-07-05 15:04:00.000 | OptIn
   1 | 1111111 | EDWARD | null | BICKLE | OptIn   | 2019-07-06 07:57:00.000 | OptOut
   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptOut  | 2019-03-03 20:51:00.000 | null
   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptIn   | 2019-03-08 19:10:00.000 | OptOut
   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptOut  | 2019-03-18 16:21:00.000 | OptIn

   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptIn   | 2019-03-21 16:38:00.000 | OptOut

   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptOut  | 2019-03-22 05:26:00.000 | OptIn
   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptIn   | 2019-04-01 15:39:00.000 | OptOut
   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptOut  | 2019-04-02 04:06:00.000 | OptIn

   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptIn   | 2019-04-06 11:53:00.000 | OptOut
   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptOut  | 2019-04-09 12:51:00.000 | OptIn

   0 | 2222222 | DAWN   | M    | ADAMS  | OptIn   | 2019-04-20 15:21:00.000 | OptOut
```

Comment: This gets me really close, is and is what I was thinking I could do. However, it appears to only bring back one OptIn/OptOut per account/person instead of each time it is changed.

Comment: @Rhonda: I am not sure what you are saying. You can see in the demo that I added to my answer that this brings back more than one record per person.

Comment: I totally agree, it does, but when I apply to my real data, it doesn't appear to work the same. I'll keep working with it.

Comment: I figured out the difference, my sample data is sorted correctly by the activity date, in reality, my actual data is not sorted correctly in the database, therefore the lag and over is not matching the date/time I expected. But your answer is what I was looking for, so thank you!